# Restart Windows service when not respond

Tags: windows, delphi, service

A legacy Service that I work is freezing due to database issues. And I'm looking for a simpler solution than fixing it.

In Aplication Form Version (Delphi), Windows recognize and show message that application is not responding.

Can Windows recognize when a service is not responding and restart the service?

In Service Properties the Recovery is only for failures.

Comment: Fix your service. It sounds like you have some threading problem. But anyway, for your situation people usually create kind of _guardian_ that interacts with the service, and if it stops responding, they restart the service process.

Comment: Without seeing your code, I can only assume based on your information that you are doing everything inside the main service thread. You should ***NEVER*** implement a service in the main thread. ***ALWAYS*** create a separate thread to do all the actual work for your service.

Comment: It´s a legacy code, and in all clients only one have this problem. I´m looking for a cheaper solution, if exists.

Comment: Few times a day the same query used several times don´t return immediately, take some minutes and return as if nothing had happened. The problem comes from the database driver with Oracle RAC. I can´t some this, and don´t have time now to change the thread.

Answer (score 5):

> In Aplication Form Version (Delphi), Windows recognize and show message that application is not responding.

Only if the main UI thread is blocked, but you shouldn't ever do anything in the main UI thread that can block it. Bad code design.

> Can Windows recognize when a service is not responding and restart the service?

Not automatically, no. You need to fix your database code so it doesn't freeze up anymore in the first place. If that is not an option (which I highly doubt) then you will have to write a separate watchdog thread/process to monitor your code/service and kill it if it freezes up. If you kill the entire service, then Windows failure actions can be used to restart it.

Comment: Yes, is not the best design, but is a legacy code with direct local database access that usually has no problem. Only one client has a problem in third partie Oracle RAC driver. I´m looking for an easy way, and if there was an auto restart it serves me.